# How can you toggle an azure storage account Networking from Enabled to Enabled Selected Networks via Azure CLI?

Tags: azure-cli, azure-storage-account

Basically I would like to toggle this setting via Azure CLI on an azure storage account that has already been created.

I need to toggle from Enabled(Selected Networks) to Enabled ( All Networks) and vice versa.

[image: Storage Account]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I have one storage account where **public network access** is "Enabled from *selected virtual networks*" like below:

[image]

To toggle from "Enabled from **Selected** Networks" to "Enabled from **All** Networks" via Azure CLI, you can make use of below command:

```bash
az storage account update --resource-group group_name --name accountname --default-action Allow
```

I ran the above command in **`Azure Cloud Shell`** where it toggled to "Enabled from **All** Networks" after one refresh like below:

[image]

Now, to  toggle from "Enabled from **All** Networks" to "Enabled from **Selected** Networks" via Azure CLI, you can make use of below command:

```bash
az storage account update --resource-group group_name --name accountname --default-action Deny
```

When I ran the above command, it again changed to "Enabled from **Selected** Networks" after one refresh like below:

[image]